# What is the best way to parse this string?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have this JavaScript string:

```
var str = "ct [b r 0 0 100 100] b r 0 0 1000 1000 c f red";
```

And would like to get an array like this:

```
['ct', ['b', 'r', 0, 0, 100, 100], 'b', 'r', 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 'c', 'f', 'red'];
```

In the original string the letters represent actions to be taken, the numbers represent coordinates and there's a nested array in there too (the second item).

I suppose the question is: How to split a string on spaces when some of the items themselves may contain (unescaped) spaces?

Comment: Can arrays be nested to an arbitrary level, or just the 1 as per your example?

Comment: _var x = JSON.stringify(str)_  it can do even json array within array

Comment: Is the input given or can you alter it? A would suggest using JSON.stringify(object) for making an string from JS object and then using JSON.parse(str) for recovering the original object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e1xhq39w/

```
var str = "ct [b r 0 0 100 100] b r 0 0 1000 1000 c f red";
var strArr = str.split(' ');
console.log(JSON.stringify(parseArray(strArr)));


function parseArray(strArr) {
    var finalArray = [];
    var tempArray = [];
    var start = -1;
    var end = -1;
    for(var i=0;i<strArr.length;i++) {
        //skip array to a temp
        if(strArr[i].indexOf('[') != -1) {
            start = i;
            tempArray.push(strArr[i].replace('[', ''));
            continue;
        }
        if(strArr[i].indexOf(']') != -1) {
            end = i;
            start = -1;
            tempArray.push(strArr[i].replace(']', ''));
            finalArray.push(parseArray(tempArray));
            continue;
        }
        if(start != -1) {
            tempArray.push(strArr[i]);
            continue;
        }
        var number = Number(strArr[i]);
        if(isNaN(number)) {         
            finalArray.push(strArr[i])
           }
        else {
            finalArray.push(number);
        }   
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try something like this:

```
var str = "ct [b r 0 0 100 100] b r 0 0 1000 1000 c f red";

// the regex picks up the first 'element' (ct), the inner array
// and all the rest
var regex = /(.*)\[(.*)\](.*)/;
var match = str.match(regex)

// take the first 'element', and add it to the rest - 
// create an array
var init = (match[1].trim() + match[3]).split(' ');

// pass it through the checkNum function
// init is an array that has strings and integers
init = checkNum(init);

// grab the inner array and run it through checkNum
var inner = checkNum(match[2].split(' '));

// splice the inner array into the main array
init.splice(1, 0, inner);

function checkNum(arr) {

    // for each element in the array, if it's conversation
    // to an integer results in NaN, return the element, otherwise
    // return the integer
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        arr[i] = isNaN(+arr[i]) ? arr[i] : +arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
['ct', ['b', 'r', 0, 0, 100, 100], 'b', 'r', 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 'c', 'f', 'red'];
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0y8eekfg/1/)

Answer (score -2):

Firstly you would have to look at the input data and determine the criteria in which you would use to split the data into individual array entities. Here, it would be ' '

JavaScript has a built in function called split, which would split the string into an array, and all you have to do is provide character which the program should look for, and when it finds this character the program will split the array at that point

```
var str = "ct [b r 0 0 100 100] b r 0 0 1000 1000 c f red";
var array = str.split(" "); //this will now store the str split into an array
```

array should be equal to:

```
ct, [b, r, 0, 0, 100, 100], b, r, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, c, f, red
```

As for the [ ]'s, I am unsure